# I am currently working on a data ana that involves examining trends across 14 var. These var have distinct scales, making visualization a bit diff

Tags: python, visualization, data-analysis, matplotlib

Scaling Issues: Many of the columns I'm analyzing are in different scales, which makes it challenging to visualize them together effectively.

Visual Representation: I initially attempted to use Matplotlib with a secondary y-axis, but the resulting plot was complex and challenging to interpret.

Time-Based Analysis: I also tried aggregating the data into monthly averages to simplify the visualization, but I still find it difficult to present the insights.

Request:
I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or best practices on:
[image]Optimal methods or tools for visualizing multivariate data with different scales.
Effective techniques to represent monthly average data.
Any other insights or strategies that might simplify the visualization and interpretation of such data?
Thank you in advance for your guidance!

Comment: You might try simplify your time series using PCA and then just visualize principal components: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/226287/176140

Comment: @Tyberius Thank you for your suggestions. Essentially, I've calculated the P-value based on Pearson correlation to identify which values can be correlated and subsequently plotted together (as shown by the red highlights in the snapshot below). I intend to plot the X-axis as the date and the Y-axis as the variable (highlighted in red in the graph below). Since I'm new to data analysis, could you please provide some guidance? The Y-axis contains various parameters with differing scales. I've attempted to use multiple secondary scales, but it still appears cluttered.

Comment: snap: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hggi9hArBADqZV3E3U-ltcK_JDLsOc6G/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your link is behind a login. If I were you, I'd plot 14 slim timelines in a ~10:1 x/y ratio, and normalize the amplitudes by their standard deviations. That should allow you to see the trends irrespective of the total amplitudes and variations. Something like this, but with more than three plots: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/shared_axis_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-shared-axis-demo-py

Comment: @MPIchael, Thanks It was very helpful.

Comment: Please don't leave us hanging and post the result!:-)

Comment: @ MPIchael, I could visualize better with shared and secondary multiple axes. Along with this, I also performed PCA analysis suggested by @Tyberius. However, I wasn't getting good results in PCA as well. When I discussed the results with my Prof., I was told that it's very hard to achieve 90% variability for field observations. However, I was able to establish that factors (Zooplankton and Phytoplankton) are affected by water temperature and nutrients and still working on it.